# Как ускорить работу объекта XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

Точная установка каких параметров может его ускорить ?

Comment: Конкретизируйте ситуацию. Вряд ли разработчики XmlHttpRequest такие глупые, что по дефолту выставили плохие значения параметров

Comment: Тут особо не конкретизируешь. Он заменяет в div-е предыдущую разметку на новый html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xhr делает запрос, он работает на столько быстро, на сколько быстр ваш канал + сервер. Откройте Chrome/FireBug -> Network и посмотрите, на что тратится время — http://www.rubaxa.org/screenshot/63dd0e5f618bf5fbe26e81837e12.png.